# Стек и указатели

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Правильный ли этот вариант реализации стека?
Не понимаю, в функцию push передается top как указатель на указатель (Node**), потому что он инициализируется на указатель pv внутри этой функции? Но когда из функции first возвращается указатель pv и на него так же инициализируется top, то top в int main - Node*. Получается top привязывается к другому указателю один раз как Node* и четыре раза как Node**?

```
#include <iostream.h>
 
/*Ниже приведена программа,которая формирует стек из пяти целых чисел (1,2,3,4,5) 
и выводит его на экран. Функция помещения в стек по традиции называется push,а выборки pop.
Указатель для работы со стеком(top) всегда ссылается на его вершину.*/
 
//Структура - элемент стека
struct Node {
    int d;         //данные элемента структуры
    Node *p;       //Указатель для связи между структурами такого же типа
};
//-----------------------------
Node *first(int d);            //Формирование первого элемента(new)
void push(Node **top,int d);   //Добавление в стек (new)
int pop(Node **top);           //Выборка из стека  (delete)
//-----------------------------
//Главная функция
int main(){
    Node *top=NULL;          //Начальная инициализация указателя-вершины нулевым адресом .       
      top=first(1);            //Создание первого элемента стека     
 
for(int i=2;i<6;i++)push(&top,i); //Добавление в стек четырёх элементов   
while(top)            //Цикл вывода на экран значений элементов стека,и удаление их из памяти.                  
{                     //Цикл длится пока на вершину(в указатель top) не попадёт нулевой адрес.
cout<<'\n';           //Переход на следующую строку в консоли.
cout<<pop(&top)<<' '; //Вывод значений возвращаемых функцией pop(...)              
}
cout<<'\n';           //Переход на следующую строку в консоли.
    return 0;       //Возвращаем,что всё норм.                  
}
//------------------------------
//Начальное формирование стека
Node *first(int d){
    Node *pv=new Node;   //Создаём элемент: структура.
    pv->d=d;             //Присваиваем полю данных значения.
    pv->p=0;             //Первый элемент даёт признак конца стека NULL нужно при выборке. 
      cout<<pv->d<<' ';    //Выводи значение поля структуры. Это тоже можно убрать.
    return pv;           //Возвращаем адрес структуры.
}
 
//Занесение в стек
void push(Node **top,int d){
Node *pv=new Node;         //Создаём элемент: структура.
pv->d=d;                   //Присваиваем полю данных значения.
pv->p=*top;                //Созданный Элемент. Связыва-ся с элементом,который сейчас на Вершине
*top=pv;                   //Созданный Элемент: помещ-тся на вершину стека вместо старой вершины
cout<<(*top)->d<<' ';      //Выводится значение Созданного элемента Этот момент можно убрать.
}
//-----------------------------
//Выборка из стека
int pop(Node **top){
int temp=(*top)->d;        //Получаем значение элемента из вершины.
Node *pv=*top;             //Получаем адрес элемента из вершины.
(*top)=(*top)->p;            //В вершину помещаем новый элемент.
delete pv;                 //Удаляем старую вершину.
return temp;               //Возвращаем значение элемента из старой вершины.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще у тебя тут реализация стека не совсем корректная у тебя тут как таковой структуры стека нет тут у тебя стек по сути это односвязный список, посети вот эту статью: [Реализация стека на С++](https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/stack-implementation-in-cpp/)
И если есть возможность лучше использовать классы и конструкторы вместо методов типа `first()` 
 Так же желательно не использовать потоки ввода/вывода в функциях, что специально не предназначены для этого или это будет очень сильно загружать ПК при большом кол-ве вызовов.

Comment: А если мне нужен именно стек через структуру как тип данных?